# How to print matrix in C using pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

I cannot figure out why the output of my program is so strange. I just wanted to print matrix with pointers, but what I get is:

```
1 7 3 8 9
10 8 9 3 4

1 7 3 8 9
7 3 8 9 10
```

What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define NK 5
#define NW 2
int sum(int *w);
int main(void) {

    srand(time(NULL));
    int T[NW][NK];
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i<NW; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j<NK; j++) {
            T[i][j] = rand() % 10 + 1;
            printf("%d ", T[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    int *wsk = T;

    printf("\n");
    sum(wsk);

    return 0;
}
int sum(int *w) {
    int i, j;
    int suma = 0;
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i<NW; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j<NK; j++) {
            printf("%d ", *((w + i)+j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: I was using *((w + i) +j) in all my programs and up to this time, it worked..

Comment: The compiler should shout at you when you assign `T` to` wsk`. Don't treat a matrix as a vector.

Comment: @JensGustedt it doesn't, whats wrong in here?

Comment: `T` is a 2D matrix and `wsk` is a vector. In that assignment expression `T` "decays" to a pointer to array of type `int (*)[NK]`, that is not the same as an `int*`. If you absolutely have to, you could use `&T[0][0]` that is the address of the first element that is stored in the matrix.

Comment: `*((w + i) + j)` --> `*((w + (i * NK)) + j)`.

Comment: But I have the impression that you have an X - Y problem. It seems that you just don't know how to declare a function that receives a matrix such that you can treat the elements in that function properly with two indices. In modern C this is easy and should be the preferred way to deal with matrices. Never do index calculations manually, the compiler knows better than you.

Comment: @Buszman LPs made a small mistake. His `NW` should be `NK`. See my version above.

Comment: `int sum(int *w)` --> `int sum(int (*w)[NK])`, `*((w + i)+j)` --> `w[i][j]`, and `sum(wsk)` --> `sum(T)` (no need for `wsk`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the geometry is fixed, you can just declare the argument with the proper type:

```
int sum(int w[NW][NK]) {
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < NW; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NK; j++) {
            printf("%d ", w[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

If you insist on passing a pointer to a linearized version:

```
int sum(int *w) {
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < NW; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NK; j++) {
            printf("%d ", w[i * NK + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `w[i * NK + j]`?

Comment: I come up for another idea. Can I just pass pointer to pointer?

Comment: @Buszman a pointer to pointer is not the same as an actual 2D array.  You have (in `int T[NW][NK]`) a 2D array, so no.